# How to retrieve data in JTable and store it another JTable for tokenizing?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tokenize

I have this code below for upload file and store it in `JTable`

```
private void jLabel1MouseReleased(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) { 
    try {
        chooser = new JFileChooser();
        chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
        chooser.showOpenDialog(null);

        File directory = chooser.getSelectedFile();
        String filename = chooser.getSelectedFile().getName();

        if (directory != null && directory.isDirectory()) {
            File[] subFiles = directory.listFiles();
            for (int i = 0; i < subFiles.length; i++) {
                DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) filelist.getModel();
                model.addRow(new Object[]{filename, subFiles[i]});
            }
            ReadDocument rf = new ReadDocument();
            String text = rf.checkReadOnlyPath(path);

            viewdoc.setText(text);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
```

And this code for call method tokenizer and after that I want to take file doc, docx or pdf from row in `JTable` to do tokenizing and I store it in another `JTable`.

```
private void jLabel16MouseReleased(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                       
    Tokenizer tokenizer;
    tokenizer = new Tokenizing();
    String output = "";

    while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
        output = output.replaceAll("[~!?.@#$%^:;&\\-*,/\\\\`'\"=()_+|\\d]|<J>.*</J>|[\\t\\r]{2,}\"]", "");
        output = output.toLowerCase();
        output += "\n" + tokenizer.nextToken();
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) Words typed in all lower case are hard to read, like trying to listen to someone who is mumbling.  Please use an upper case letter at the start of sentences, for the word I, and proper names like `ArrayList` or Oracle. 2) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).  3) But more to the point, what have you actually tried in order to implement the required functionality?  Where did you get stuck and why?  Have you completed the [table tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html)?

Comment: Data displayed in a `JTable` is _stored_ in the `TableModel`; focus on transferring from one _model_ to another.